# Cannot AddObject to NSMutableArray from Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsexception

I have a feeling that my problem here is really with blocking, but maybe it's something else too. I am trying to forward geocode an address and place the coordinates into an array to use later.

An exception is raised down at the bottom when I try to call on one of the objects I tried added to the array in the block. The exception also gets raised before any of the NSLogs ever print out within the block text.

What's the proper way to handle this?  Thanks.

```
 - (NSMutableArray *)convertAddressToGeocode:(NSString *)addressString
{
    //return array with lat/lng
    __block NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString
             completionHandler:^ (NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) {
                 for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
                 {
                     // Process the placemark.
                     if (error){
                         NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                         [self displayError:error];
                         return;
                     }
                     else {

                         NSArray const *keys = @[@"coordinate.latitude",
                                                 @"coordinate.longitude",
                                                 @"altitude",
                                                 @"horizontalAccuracy",
                                                 @"verticalAccuracy",
                                                 @"course",
                                                 @"speed",
                                                 @"timestamp"];

                         NSString *keylat = keys[0];
                         NSString *keylng = keys[1];

                         if (aPlacemark.location == nil)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"location is nil.");

                         }
                         else if ([keylat isEqualToString:@"coordinate.latitude"] && [keylng isEqualToString:@"coordinate.longitude"])
                         {
                             NSString *lat = @"";
                             NSString *lng = @"";
                             lat = [self displayStringForDouble: [aPlacemark.location coordinate].latitude];
                             lng = [self displayStringForDouble: [aPlacemark.location coordinate].longitude];

                             NSLog(@"This never gets executed"): //THIS NEVER GETS EXECUTED
                             [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lat]];
                             [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lng]];
                         }}}}];
NSLog(@"Array: %@", coordinates[0]);  //EXCEPTION RAISED HERE, Nothing ever gets added
return coordinates;
}
```

Here is the code this method is supposed to be plugged into, but I'm not getting the coordinates out of convertAddresstoGeocode to pass to convertCoordinatestoRepModel:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *addressToSearch = self.addressSearchField.text;
    NSMutableArray *coordinateArray = [self convertAddressToGeocode:addressToSearch];
    NSMutableArray *repModelArray = [self convertCoordinatesToRepModel:coordinateArray];
...
}
```

Comment: set some breakpoints under every "if", and see what going on

Comment: [initWithCapacity:0] sheepy

Comment: Just nicer is to `coordinates = [NSMutableArray array];` But that is not what causes your problem.

Comment: @PuneethKamath you are wrong, It is just for optimisation, From apple docs: Mutable arrays expand as needed; numItems simply establishes the object’s initial capacity.

Comment: Check your 'placemarks' array count..

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to pass this array I am creating to another class method. But I am returning an empty array to the next  function.

Comment: what's the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `geocodeAddressString` is async operation than your block will be performed after

```
NSLog(@"Array: %@", coordinates[0]);
```

also, after call of your method ends (when event already handled) the coordinates array 
released (it is because of __block modifier - blocks do not retain objects with __block modifier), and in your block you try to use dealloced `coordinates` array.

**Once again:**

Your block will be called after `NSLog(@"Array: %@", coordinates[0]);`

**f.e.:**

1. Remove `NSLog(@"Array: %@", coordinates[0]);` - it is normal that in that moment array is empty.
2. Store your `coordinates` array in some `@property` , you can release it after using in block

**UPDATE:**

in .h file

```
typedef void (^ConverteArrayCallback)(NSArray *coordinates);
```

under `@intrerface`

```
- (void)convertAddressToGeocode:(NSString *)addressString callback:(ConverteArrayCallback) callback;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)convertAddressToGeocode:(NSString *)addressString callback:(ConverteArrayCallback) callback { 
    NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:addressString
             completionHandler:^ (NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error) {
                 for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
                 {
                     // Process the placemark.
                     if (error){
                         NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                         [self displayError:error];
                         return;
                     }
                     else {

                         NSArray const *keys = @[@"coordinate.latitude",
                                                 @"coordinate.longitude",
                                                 @"altitude",
                                                 @"horizontalAccuracy",
                                                 @"verticalAccuracy",
                                                 @"course",
                                                 @"speed",
                                                 @"timestamp"];

                         NSString *keylat = keys[0];
                         NSString *keylng = keys[1];

                         if (aPlacemark.location == nil)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"location is nil.");

                         }
                         else if ([keylat isEqualToString:@"coordinate.latitude"] && [keylng isEqualToString:@"coordinate.longitude"])
                         {
                             NSString *lat = @"";
                             NSString *lng = @"";
                             lat = [self displayStringForDouble: [aPlacemark.location coordinate].latitude];
                             lng = [self displayStringForDouble: [aPlacemark.location coordinate].longitude];

                                 NSLog(@"This never gets executed"): //THIS NEVER GETS EXECUTED
                                 [coordinates addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lat]];
                                 [coordinates addObject:[NSString s

tringWithFormat:@"%@",lng]];
                                 }}}

                           if (callback != NULL) {
                                 callback(coordinates);
                           }

      }];
}
```

That should works!

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *addressToSearch = self.addressSearchField.text;
    [self convertAddressToGeocode:addressToSearch callback:^(NSArray *coordinates)
      {  
       self.textView.text = [coordinates objectAtIndex:0];
      }];
}
```

Comment: In order to update the @property coordinates, should i turn this method into a (void) rather than an NSMutable array method?

Comment: @user2033783 yes, you should turn it into void, if you need to get callback after array will be filled, you can pass block with needed parameters as parameter of method

Comment: f.e. typedef void (^ConverteArrayCallback)(NSArray *coordinates);

Comment: - (NSMutableArray *)convertAddressToGeocode:(NSString *)addressString callback:(ConverteArrayCallback) callback { ... }

Comment: @user2033783 please, check updated solution, i have not access to XCode now :)

Comment: Wow, thank you. Okay, I have one stupid question now - I'll probably get it from the documentation first, but who knows. When I call your new void method in my main, what do I pass for callback?

Comment: something like that: ^(NSArray *coordinates){
  // do what you want with recived coordinates
}

Comment: (I figured TedCap is easier to type) - My sticking point is still what to do at that callback in
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{...}
How to pass this coordinate array to the next function. Also, should these NSArray's all be NSMutableArrays like we use in convertAddressToGeocode ?

Comment: @TedCap mmm... what did you want to do after calling convertAddressToGeocode? this is what, exactly

Comment: When you say "do what you want with received coordinates" you don't mean just drop the next statement into the brackets? like callback:^(NSArray *coordinates){NSMutableArray *coordinateArray = coordinates};

Comment: @TedCap performing a async operation and wating it's result while user typing something in UI main thread is not good design, you should rework your user interface

Comment: @TedCap What are you going to do at textFieldShouldReturn with result coordinates?

Comment: Something like this? [self convertAddressToGeocode:addressToSearch callback:^(NSMutableArray *coordinates){NSMutableArray* coordinateArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:coordinates];}];

Comment: @TedCap it makes no sense, in your example you just declare array in local scope of block, you should read documentation about blocks and how they works. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW1   Do you understand that in convertAddressToGeocode: ASYNC operation is performed?

Comment: Yeah, I do in theory, but clearly not in practice! I think I'm close. I'll update the post when I get it working. Thanks so much for your help. I  really appreciate it.

Comment: What I'm doing is taking a user generated string (an address), geocoding it, then using the information to update labels in the UI.

Comment: Oh yes, now it works. Thanks so much, Pavel. You were absolutely right too that I was thinking about it entirely the wrong way.

Answer (score -1):

```
__block NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
```

The problem is here; just replace the above code with:

```
NSMutableArray *coordinates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: why, what the problem with capacity? It is just for optimisation, am I wrong?

Comment: From apple docs:
Mutable arrays expand as needed; numItems simply establishes the object’s initial capacity.